# String stream output compare

Tags: c++, stringstream, stdstring

I want to compare output of stringstream with some string.

Problem is when I use fill and width on stringstream I cant compare resulting string with preloaded string.

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr.fill(' ');
sstr.width(4);
sstr <<  4 <<  std::endl;
if("   4" == sstr.str()){
 std::cout <<  "Equal" <<  std::endl;
}
```

It's not equal. My educated guess would be that width somehow use some kind of flag or other kind of indicator to replace bunch of spaces in string. But I am not sure and didn't find anything useful on google. Does anyone know why I cannot compare that (sstream.str() and targeted string)?

Goal is to test what will stringstream (which is heart of my component) print on console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also inserted a `std::endl` into the string. That's going to add a newline character to the string.

Remove the `std::endl` from your output.